# Cannot reach class parameter in function

Tags: function, kotlin, parameter-passing

I cannot reach class parameter (application) in class function.
Explain please what's the reasoning behind that? Why parameter is accessable within class body but isn't from class function?

```
class VM_MainActivity(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

val taskEntities:List<TaskEntity>?= Repository(application.applicationContext).taskEntities //"application" is reachable

  fun fillWithSampleData() {
    Repository(**application**.applicationContext).fillDBwithSampleData()  //error: Unresolved refernce: application
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `application` is a parameter passed to the constructor.  It's only available while an instance is being constructed: while running any `init { }` blocks, and initialising any properties.  (The latter is why you can use it to initialise `taskEntities`.)  It doesn't persist after that.

If you want your instance to ‘remember’ the value of the parameter, add `val` (or `var`) before it, to make it a property:

```
class VM_MainActivity(val application: Application) // …
```